# Bulk ref cursor into nested table showing error

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, bulkinsert

1. I Created a nested table
2. I Want to bulk ref cursor (C_get_cards) into the nested table created.
3. I Want to use nested table as one of the column in table `STAT_QUERIES`.

How do I combine all the three steps in a single procedure? Please correct me if my approach is wrong.

```
--Nested Table---
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_card_details AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20)  -- define type
    /
    CREATE TYPE Query AS OBJECT (  -- create object
       CARD_QUERY T_card_details)  -- declare nested table as attribute
    /
    CREATE TABLE STAT_QUERIES (
    OBJECTTYPE     VARCHAR2(50),
    CATEGORY       VARCHAR2(100),
    CARD_QUERY     T_card_details)
    NESTED TABLE CARD_QUERY STORE AS CARD_QUERY_TAB;     
    select * FROM STAT_QUERIES

    -- The cursor bulk collect into T_CARD details
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NRMSP_INVENTORYSTATS IS
    CURSOR C_get_cards
      IS
        SELECT 
         nt.name     nt_name
        ,nd.name     nd_name
        ,ct.name     ct_name
        ,ps.name     ps_name
        ,count(c.cardid) 
        FROM cardtype ct, card c, node n, nodetype nt, nodedef nd, provisionstatus ps
        WHERE ct.name in ('SRA AMP', 'XLA AMP', 'SAM', 'ESAM')
        AND ct.cardtypeid = c.card2cardtype
        AND c.card2node = n.nodeid
        AND n.node2nodetype = nt.nodetypeid
        AND n.node2nodedef = nd.nodedefid
        AND c.card2provisionstatus = ps.provisionstatusid
        GROUP by nt.name, nd.name, ct.name, ps.name
      ;
        TYPE cards_TAB_TYPE IS TABLE OF C_get_cards%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER ;
        T_card_details              cards_TAB_TYPE ;
    BEGIN
      OPEN C_get_cards ;
        FETCH C_get_cards
          BULK COLLECT INTO T_card_details
          LIMIT 250 
        ;

    END;
    /
    ---INSERT INTO STAT_QUERIES---

    INSERT INTO STAT_QUERIES
    VALUES('CARD', 'Cards from Other Projects 2014', 'CARD_QUERY');
```

Comment: Well, what error do you get? You don't seem to be calling your procedure, or using the Query type, and you're trying to insert a plain string into your nested table column. I'm not really sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: @AlexPoole, I basically want my refcursor to output into the nested table. The nested table is supposed to be one of my table column in one of the other tables.